# My for loop for Graphics g return a NullPointerException

Tags: java

Sorry for such a basic question, but I'm losing my mind here..

**Here is my code**:

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {

    for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
        for(int x=0;x<2100;x+=210){
            for(int y=0;y<2100;y+=210){
   g.drawImage(img[i], x, y,200,200, null);
            }
  // g.drawImage(img2, WIDTH, WIDTH, jc);
 }
    }
 }
```

That method which I used to draw multiple images to an applet caused a NullPointerException

Anybody knows why?

Thanks in advance
:)

**My image**:

```
 public void loadimg(File fn){

         try{

            // File fn =  jc.getSelectedFile();
             for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
              img[i] = ImageIO.read(fn).getSubimage(3881, 923, 673, 713);
               repaint();
             }

         }
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

     }
```

is something wrong with my code? It isn't finish yet but sub image should be splitting the image separately.. thanks

Sorry for my bad english.

by the way, this is my complete code

```
package afisapplet;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
//import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import afisapplet.Afisapplet;


public class displayaplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {
JFileChooser jc = new JFileChooser();
     private BufferedImage img[];
     //private BufferedImage img2;
     Button b = new Button("Scan");
      Button c = new Button("View");
     // Button d = new Button("Select Image"); 
static Afisapplet afap ;
     public void init() {


      b.addActionListener(this);
      c.addActionListener(this);
      add(b);
      add(c);

     }


     public void paint(Graphics g) {

        for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
            for(int x=0;x<2100;x+=210){
                for(int y=0;y<2100;y+=210){
       g.drawImage(img[i], x, y,200,200, null);
                }
      // g.drawImage(img2, WIDTH, WIDTH, jc);
     }
        }
     }

     public void scan(){
         try{
          afap = new Afisapplet();   
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
         public void loadimg(File fn){

             try{

                // File fn =  jc.getSelectedFile();
                 for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
                  img[i] = ImageIO.read(fn).getSubimage(3881, 923, 673, 713);
                    repaint();
                 }

             }
             catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

         }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Button source= (Button) ae.getSource();
if(source.getLabel() == "Scan"){
scan();
}
      if(source.getLabel() == "View"){
           int returnVal=     jc.showOpenDialog(c);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File fn = jc.getSelectedFile();
                loadimg(fn);


            } else {
                return;
            }



      }      

//To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }



}
```

UPDATE
i've debugged my file, it returns that my `img[]` is null because i've used a button to call JFileChooser and then invoke my `loadimg()` method. therefore before i choose a file it would return a NullPointerException error, but when i've chosen a file, it still return a NullPointerException.. what should I do?
thanks :)

UPDATE CLOSED
sorry for my noob mistakes, i forgot to declare array size in the beginning :p

Comment: I would need to see the rest of your code, what are you doing?

Comment: how do you get `img`?

Comment: Set breakpoint at "g.drawImage(img[i], x, y,200,200, null);" run and check if g is null or img is null; then check img[1]..img[12] if they nulls

Comment: where do you put someting in `img[]`?

Comment: is there a reason to have int i, x, and y done the way you have it, why not for(int i = 1; i < 12; i++){ . That would tidy the code up a small bit. Next thing is null suggests exactly that, something is null, do you have the img array initialized? also why do u have 3 for loops? if you are creating a 2d map (x and y coord's) what are you hoping to achieve with 3 for loops?

Comment: @tommyknocker ok i can remove that int i,x,y but for 3 loop i think it will draw image like tile.. so my full image can be splitted and displayed all at the same time in the applet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize your `BufferedImage` array!

So instead of this:

```
private BufferedImage img[];
```

try this (if you have only these 11 images):

```
private BufferedImage img[] = new BufferedImage[11];
```

This should solve the `NullPointerException` issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
  for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
              img[i] = ImageIO.read(fn).getSubimage(3881, 923, 673, 713);
               repaint();
             }
```

you are populating an array of images between 0 and 11 here

```
   for(i=1;i<12;i++){
        for(x=1;x<2100;x+=210){
            for(y=1;y<2100;y+=210){
   g.drawImage(img[i], x, y,200,200, null);
            }
```

You are looping through an array of images 0 to 12 here

Answer (score 0):

You should debug if your parameter g is passed correctly and also if your index `i` is not out of range.